# The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted in ASP

Tags: asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

```
Source Error: 


[No relevant source lines]

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9ef9c2bd\671c7ce5\App_Web_qg01vw5e.2.cs    Line: 0 

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: inputString]
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString, Purpose purpose) +9871443
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter2.Deserialize(String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +8
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, String serializedState, Purpose purpose) +40
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +127

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: 127.0.0.1
    Port: 2802
    Referer: http://myserver.com:47135/Tamplete.aspx
    Path: /Tamplete.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.146 Safari/537.36
    ViewState: ]

[HttpException (0x80004005): The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.]
   System.Web.UI.ViewStateException.ThrowError(Exception inner, String persistedState, String errorPageMessage, Boolean macValidationError) +156
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +266
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadPageStateFromPersistenceMedium() +238
   System.Web.UI.Page.LoadAllState() +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +6704
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +245
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() +72
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) +21
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) +58
   ASP.tamplete_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\9ef9c2bd\671c7ce5\App_Web_qg01vw5e.2.cs:0
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +341
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69
```

Comment: / is your root so something is seriously wrong with your build. Have you tried a clean and rebuild?

Comment: Clean the solution and run again.

Answer (score 0):

Clean the solution and run again. 
Or remove the Temporary from `c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`